# Python and openpyxl - Changing column width to fit?

Tags: python, width, openpyxl

Say I had a workbook, and I wanted to make sure that all columns are readable; how would I determine the width the column needs to be from a cell's text, to then change the width of the column?

Comment: Sadly, as noted by @Charlie Clark, the bestFit attribute is not that helpful and there is no method provided within the library to do this. There are [some answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529662/python-automatically-adjust-width-of-an-excel-files-columns) for manual workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do this accurately: column widths are calculated using the typeface installed on the computer system with some padding. So you can only work with a best guess.

You can set the `bestFit` attribute for a column but this often doesn't do what you expect.

From the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) § 18.3.1.13:

> 'Best fit' is set to true under these conditions:
>
> - The column width has never been manually set by the user, AND
> - The column width is not the default width
> - 'Best fit' means that when numbers are typed into a cell contained in   a 'best fit' column, the column width should automatically resize to  display the number.

Comment: Can you provide a few lines of code to demonstrate? Does the variable width issue go away with a fixed width typeface?

Comment: @flywire check out the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39529662/python-automatically-adjust-width-of-an-excel-files-columns) if you haven't already...