# Python - Automatically adjust width of an excel file's columns

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Newbie - I have a Python script that adjusts the width of different columns of an excel file, according to the values specified:

```
import openpyxl
from string import ascii_uppercase

newFile = "D:\Excel Files\abc.xlsx"

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = newFile)        
worksheet = wb.active

for column in ascii_uppercase:
    if (column=='A'):
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 30
    elif (column=='B'):
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 40            
    elif (column=='G'):
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 45            
    else:
        worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 15

wb.save(newFile)
```

Is there any way through which we can adjust the width of every column to its most optimum value, without explicitly specifying it for different columns (means, without using this "**if-elif-elif-......-elif-else**" structure)? 
Thanks!

Comment: Use a dictionary of column names and widths. As the file format requires values per column, there is no magic way to do this.

Comment: Related: [Auto-adjust column widths with xlwt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929115/python-xlwt-accessing-existing-cell-content-auto-adjust-column-width). The issues surrounding column widths are basically the same no matter what package you're using. The linked question has an answer based on widths for Arial 10 (the default font in older .xls files). A similar technique could be used for Calibri 11 (default for .xlsx files).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
for col in worksheet.columns:
     max_length = 0
     column = col[0].column_letter # Get the column name
     for cell in col:
         try: # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
             if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                 max_length = len(str(cell.value))
         except:
             pass
     adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
     worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
```

This could probably be made neater but it does the job. You will want to play around with the adjusted_width value according to what is good for the font you are using when viewing it. If you use a monotype you can get it exact but its not a one-to-one correlation so you will still need to adjust it a bit.

If you want to get fancy and exact without monotype you could sort letters by width and assign each width a float value which you then add up. This would require a third loop parsing each character in the cell value and summing up the result for each column and probably a dictionary sorting characters by width, perhaps overkill but cool if you do it.

Edit: Actually there seems to be a better way of measuring visual size of text: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32565855/6839055) personally I would prefer the matplotlib technique.

Hope I could be of help, my very first stackoverflow answer =)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197574/python-openpyxl-column-width-size-adjust?rq=1) this question basically covers your topic as well.

Comment: I think there's a bug here that prevent proper operation on numerical cell values. In line 8, instead of `max_length = len(cell.value)` I think it should be `max_length = len(str(cell.value))`

Comment: In what circumstance is the try / except is needed? I don't seem to reach the except block with empty values.

Answer (score 24):

Updated version as of openpyxl 3.0.0 (using .columns fails with `TypeError: expected <class 'str'>`:

```
for column_cells in ws.columns:
    length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    ws.column_dimensions[column_cells[0].column_letter].width = length
```

Comment: adding the filter for unmerged cells as suggested by @virako
     `for column_cells in ws.columns:`

         `unmerged_cells = list(filter(lambda cell_to_check: cell_to_check.coordinate not in ws.merged_cells, column_cells))`

         `length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in unmerged_cells)`

         `ws.column_dimensions[unmerged_cells[0].column_letter].width = length * 1.2`

Comment: @DušanAtanacković good to hear. I have put this as a github gist for easier readability - https://gist.github.com/arvsr1988/4468e7f9bb9c5f3aa514eea6a14804b6

Comment: This works but I had to replace as_text() with str()

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 8):

With the latest openpyxl you can use this:

```
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
for idx, col in enumerate(worksheet.columns, 1):
    worksheet.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(idx)].auto_size = True
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything at all; column is the same as before; see also first comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60248319) (`bestFit` seems to be an alias for `auto_size`).

Comment: Not working for me

Comment: for me it hides the column(s) instead auto-size them.

Comment: @CristianF. I faced the same for some versions. It's weird.

Comment: I believe this instruction works perfectly for LibreOffice, but not for Excel. When the latter opens the file it doesn't understand it and hides column.

Comment: For me it looked better when I also set the `cell.alignment.warp_text=True`.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comment above and add this post [openpyxl - adjust column width size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197574/openpyxl-adjust-column-width-size). I succeeded, but the answer should be:

```py
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

for col in ws.columns:
    max_length = 0
    column = get_column_letter(col[0].column)  # Get the column name
    # Since Openpyxl 2.6, the column name is  ".column_letter" as .column became the column number (1-based)
    for cell in col:
        try:  # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
            if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                max_length = len(cell.value)
        except:
            pass
    adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
    ws.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
```

i'm using openpyxl = "^3.0.5"

Answer (score 4):

I have a problem with merged_cells and autosize not work correctly, if you have the same problem, you can solve adding the next lines inside code of [oldsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6839055/oldsea)

```
for col in worksheet.columns:
    max_length = 0
    column = col[0].column # Get the column name
    for cell in col:
        if cell.coordinate in worksheet.merged_cells: # not check merge_cells
            continue
        try: # Necessary to avoid error on empty cells
            if len(str(cell.value)) > max_length:
                max_length = len(cell.value)
        except:
            pass
    adjusted_width = (max_length + 2) * 1.2
    worksheet.column_dimensions[column].width = adjusted_width
```

Answer (score 2):

## Just insert the below line of code in your file. That's it (install the mentioned libraries if you don't have)

```
# Imorting the necessary modules
try:
        from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
        from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
        from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook



for column_cells in sheet.columns:
    new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
    if new_column_length > 0:
        sheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for column_cells in sheet.columns:
    new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
    if new_column_length > 0:
        sheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def auto_format_cell_width(ws):
    for letter in range(1,ws.max_column):
        maximum_value = 0
        for cell in ws[get_column_letter(letter)]:
            val_to_check = len(str(cell.value))
            if val_to_check > maximum_value:
               maximum_value = val_to_check
        ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(letter)].width = maximum_value + 1
```

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Is this not quite similar to existing solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
sheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
```

The above line of code fits the adjust the width of the column to best fit

Comment: You need to explain little more

Comment: Okay Sir. I will

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me:

```py
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

for columns in worksheet.columns:
    col = get_column_letter(columns[0].column)
    worksheet.column_dimensions[col].auto_size = True
```