# How to set column width to bestFit in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have filled a worksheet with some data and I'm trying to make column widths to assume their best fit, as in [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/03/16/autofit-excel-columns-rows/). Basically the kind of autofit that happens when you double-click the column width adjustment separator.

This is my minimal example, which, as far as my understanding of `openpyxl` documentation goes, should work:

```
import openpyxl
from typing import NoReturn

def columns_best_fit(ws: openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet) -> NoReturn:
    """
    Make all columns best fit
    """
    column_letters = tuple(openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(col_number + 1) for col_number in range(ws.max_column))
    for column_letter in column_letters:
        dim = openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions.ColumnDimension(ws, index=column_letter, bestFit=True, customWidth=True)
        ws.column_dimensions[column_letter] = dim


wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.append(("Long Column Header 1", "Even Longer Column Header 2"))
ws.append(("some data", "more data"))
columns_best_fit(ws)
wb.save("column_width_test.xlsx")
```

However, when I open the resulting file, the columns are just slightly wider, but certainly not best fit.

Comment: Column widths must unfortunately be **always** be calculated. Setting `bestWidth=True` has no effect.

Comment: Useful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14450572/7232335).

Comment: Here is the original bug ticket: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1275
TLDR; `WONTFIX`

Answer (score 15):

After many hours of research finally, I found it.

NOTE : In the below code, **sheet** is the worksheet name. Usually in the documentation, we can see it as **ws**. Please don't forget to change the worksheet name.

```
# Imorting the necessary modules
try:
        from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
        from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
        from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook



for column_cells in sheet.columns:
    new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
    new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
    if new_column_length > 0:
        sheet.column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
```

UPDATE : This code doesn't work for all, but don't hesitate to try it

Comment: How about linking the reference you found? Auto-adjust column width is normally fine with fixed-width fonts but poor with proportional fonts, especially if zoom is applied to the sheet.

Comment: Hi Sir,
Could you please elaborate on your question? I didn't get it.
Didn't this solution help you?

Comment: "After many hours of research finally, I found it." Can you link the reference?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the link. I will paste here If I get

Answer (score 4):

I have edited your function. It should work now.

```
def columns_best_fit(ws: openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet) -> NoReturn:
        """
        Make all columns best fit
        """
        column_letters = tuple(openpyxl.utils.get_column_letter(col_number + 1) for col_number in range(ws.max_column))
        for column_letter in column_letters:
            ws.column_dimensions[column_letter].bestFit = True
```

Comment: no difference with auto_size

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @Mounesh answer, it seems like the workbook isn't saved after setting the column width. This would work.

```
# Imorting the necessary modules
try:
        from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
except ImportError:
        from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
        from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook


workbook = load_workbook("excel_name.xlsx")
for sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
  for column_cells in workbook[sheet_name].columns:
        new_column_length = max(len(str(cell.value)) for cell in column_cells)
        new_column_letter = (get_column_letter(column_cells[0].column))
        if new_column_length > 0:
            workbook[sheet_name].column_dimensions[new_column_letter].width = new_column_length*1.23
workbook.save("excel_name.xlsx")
```

Answer (score -1):

I used some like this:

```
from openpyxl.worksheet.dimensions import ColumnDimension

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ColumnDimension(ws, bestFit=True)
```